# Use pipenv on server with capistrano - Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: python, capistrano

I have project which uses pipenv.

in local

pipenv works very useful.

```
$pipenv shell
$python manage.py runserver
```

I deploy the project with capistrano,

What I want to do is start `pipenv shell` start `uwsgi` server.

However when exec this script in capistrano

```
task :bundle do on roles(:app) do
   execute "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pipenv shell"
end
```

this error occurs

```
termios.error: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')
```

---

**Trial**

I use `pipenv run` and try this,

```
task :bundle do on roles(:app) do
   execute "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pipenv install"
end
end

task :migrate do on roles(:app) do
    execute "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pipenv run python #{release_path}/manage.py makemigrations"
    execute "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pipenv run python #{release_path}/manage.py migrate"
end
end
```

Install is successful however, pip module is not recoginized.

```
 DEBUG [50051834] Command: /home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pipenv install
 DEBUG [50051834]   Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (db4242)...
 DEBUG [50051834]        ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/0 — 00:00:00
 DEBUG [50051834]   
 DEBUG [50051834]   To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
  INFO [50051834] Finished in 1.239 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [8a6402ea] Running /home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pipenv run python /var/www/html/sokuapi/releases/20220901070724/manage.py makemigrations as ubuntu@koala.example.jp
 DEBUG [8a6402ea] Command: /home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pipenv run python /var/www/html/sokuapi/releases/20220901070724/manage.py makemigrations
 DEBUG [8a6402ea]   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/sokuapi/releases/20220901070724/manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Comment: `pipenv shell` is an interactive command, not something you typically run from automation like capistrano because it blocks until the shell exits.

Comment: Thank you for your comment,,, I see.. So, I can't use pipenv on server. However when I need to deploy a few django projects on server, how can devide the pip environment?

Comment: I tried to use `pyenv run` instead of  pyenv shell` ,then updated the article. any help appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend to use `pipenv requirments` [doc](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#generating-a-requirements-txt) to generate `requirments.txt` and deploy your application by `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: @HALF9000 Thank you, but I have multiple django projects on the same server. `pip3 install -r requirements.txt` combines the pip library, doesn't it?  I want to separate the environments for each projects.

Comment: For now, this problem is solved. thanks to  
@jordanm
 comment. then my problem progresses, I made another article here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73567955/how-can-set-environment-for-python-when-there-are-multiple-django-projects-on-on