# How can set environment for python when there are multiple django projects on one server?

Tags: python, django, linux

I have a server which has this structure.

```
Nginx -> uwsgi(port:8011) DjangoA
      -> uwsgi(port:8012) DjangoB
```

I developed with `pipenv` in local.

```
pipenv shell
pipenv manage.py runserver
```

Now I want to put this on server with

At first I try this on `capistrano`

```
task :bundle do on roles(:app) do
   #execute "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pip install -r #{release_path}/requirements.txt"
   execute "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pipenv install"
end
end

task :migrate do on roles(:app) do
    execute "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pipenv run python #{release_path}/manage.py makemigrations"
    execute "/home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pipenv run python #{release_path}/manage.py migrate"
end
end

task :assets do on roles(:app) do
    execute "yes yes | /home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pipenv run python #{release_path}/manage.py collectstatic"
end
end
```

However even after pipenv installing , there is no library appears. (or it is not correctly installed??)

```
 DEBUG [50051834] Command: /home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pipenv install
 DEBUG [50051834]   Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (db4242)...
 DEBUG [50051834]        ▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉▉ 0/0 — 00:00:00
 DEBUG [50051834]   
 DEBUG [50051834]   To activate this project's virtualenv, run pipenv shell.
Alternatively, run a command inside the virtualenv with pipenv run.
  INFO [50051834] Finished in 1.239 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [8a6402ea] Running /home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pipenv run python /var/www/html/sokuapi/releases/20220901070724/manage.py makemigrations as ubuntu@koala.example.jp
 DEBUG [8a6402ea] Command: /home/ubuntu/.pyenv/shims/pipenv run python /var/www/html/sokuapi/releases/20220901070724/manage.py makemigrations
 DEBUG [8a6402ea]   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/sokuapi/releases/20220901070724/manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

So, I have a few questions.

- Is it possible to use pipenv to separate the environment in one server??
- Is there any other best practice to separate enviroment on server?